# UITesting Custom Views In Swift

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am new to Swift, looking for writing a UITest for a custom view which conforms to UIView and UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. This is kind of drawing a Signature in a canvas. I am looking for a way to check whether the drawing area has any value present.

Assume MyView.signature returns the signature (UIImage) user draws on the canvas.
I wanted to test like like this.

```
let canvas = app.otherElements["SignatureAccessibilityIdentifier"]
XCTAssertNil(canvas.value) or XCTAssertNotNil(canvas.value)
```

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The values are meant for VoiceOver users. To check the mentioned behavior with UI tests you should check other up changes like Done button becoming enabled. Alternatively, you can set two different accessibility identifiers (which are meant for testing purposes) before and after interaction with your custom element.

Comment: It would probably be better to give the signature view a user-friendly accessibilityValue denoting whether there is a signature or not. This has the added benefit of giving VoiceOver users more context, and can be tested just as easily with XCTest.